# How to SOAP API Python request with keys

Tags: soap, wsdl, suds, zeep

After spending an entire day on trying to make things work (watching tutorials, reading through wikipedia and blogs), I thought it could be a good idea to ask some experts here on stack overflow.

So I am in the following situation:

- I am trying to extract some information using an SOAP API with python
- I have access to an URL and the WSDL definition (url ends with .php)
- A PDF document which says, that when accesing the API I need to provide a NameB object with valid set of identification keys. (HOW DO I DO THIS?)
- Valid set of keys
- I have tried both the zeep library and suds.client without any success

Could somebody explain to me what I need to do in order to receive the desired data?

The WSDL definition looks something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">     
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">         
        <NameA>             
            <body>                 
                 <NameB>                     
                             <Guid1>GUID</Guid1>                                                    
                             <Guid2>GUID</Guid2>                 
                 </NameB>     
                 <Include>1</Include>                 
                 <NumberA> Number_A </NumberA>             
            </body>         
         </NameA>     
     </s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

I assume that I need to enter the keys between elements Guid1 and Guid2, but HOW?

As you might read between the lines I am not an expert with python.

Thank you in advance! I am grateful for any kind of help!

Please let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert but I am also using ZEEP and Python to call SOAP services.

"that when accesing the API I need to provide a NameB object with valid set of identification keys. (HOW DO I DO THIS?)"

try creating an object and pass it to the call.
NameB = {
'Guid1': your_value,
'Guid2': your_value
}

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I have already found a different solution on:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/making-soap-api-calls-using-python/